# TwidoSuite counter: How to connect D output to R input?

Tags: plc, twido-suite

I'm trying to add a counter to a Twido Suite program, but I don't know how to make it set to zero when the preset - `C0.P` - is reached.

The docs say the `D` output is activated, and the `R` input resets the counter to zero, but I can't connect the `D` output directly to the `R` input.

[image]

This is the List equivalent to this Ladder diagram above:

```
BLK   %C0
LD    BLINK
CU
END_BLK
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by using a intermediate bit variable:

[image]